# Get a list of top goal scorers

Tags: mysql, sql

What query should I use if I want a list of top goal scorers. Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c53e78/1).

The result should be:

```
player_id | goals
1           5
2           2
3           1
```

Comment: `SELECT player_id, SUM(goals) FROM goal GROUP BY player_id;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: I don't understand your sense of 'top'. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT player_id, sum(goals) goals 
FROM goal GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY goals desc;
```

will help you.